# Updating to latest version of 5.10 LTS kernel

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I've been updating my kernel for months using this website [ubuntu mainline kernels](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D)

So from base 5.10 up to 5.10.36 it's been okay and i'm able to download the packages and update my kernel, but after 5.10.36 after downloading the packages, I've encountered some errors.. after 5.10.36 i tried again, and then got errors again... i noticed that files in the directory are the wrong version

From [v5.10.46 Mainline Test](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.46/)

```
Test amd64/build succeeded (rc=0, on=amd64, time=0:23:06, log=amd64/log)
amd64/linux-headers-5.11.0-20-generic_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
amd64/linux-headers-5.11.0-20-lowlatency_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
amd64/linux-headers-5.11.0-20_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_all.deb
amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-20-generic_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-20-lowlatency_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
amd64/linux-modules-5.11.0-20-generic_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
amd64/linux-modules-5.11.0-20-lowlatency_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
amd64/linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-20-generic_5.11.0-20.21+21.10.1_amd64.deb
```

Is this a mistake? or I'm just missing something? I'm using elementary OS 5.1 by the way.

Comment: Hi just wondering could you possibly post what errors you are getting?, from what I see here i don't see anything wrong besides the version type but no matter what you said you are updating to 5.10.36 and the site says 5.10.46 and the files say 5.11.0, is there a reason this is explicitly bad? Also any more information you could provide would be great, but overall i do not see why you are updating the kernel through a ppa or anything but your package manager, is there a reason you need not to go through apt? my recommendation though from what you have posted is just to go through apt from now

Comment: Looks like Ubuntu screwed up, and fixed it in 5.0.47: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.47/ points to 5.10.x versions again.